# How to get last modification time and timezone of a remote server via FTP (perl)

Tags: linux, perl, ftp, cgi, synchronization

I am writing a perl script that can sync a local directory with remote directory incremently using FTP. It checks last modified date of each file and compare it with one remote file's. I use the following code to get last modified time via FTP.

```
 my $f = Net::FTP->new($config->{'host'}, Passive => 1, Debug => 0) || die "Couldn't ftp to $config->{'host'}: $@";
 $f->mdtm($file);
```

It works great if local machine and remote machine have same time and timezone, I need to get a workaround if they are not!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't exist a way to know the timezone set for an FTP Server using only ftp commands ... Anyway, *if you have write permission you could try creating a file on the remote FTP Server and then
doing an "ls" on it to see the date/time stamp, having the timestamp of the newly created file you could calculate the difference between your local timezone and the server time zone*.

```
$f->touch('test.time') or die $f->message; #Creates new zero byte file
$f->mdtm('test.time'); #Now you should have the local time of the FTP Server
#Now you can compare with your local time and find the difference ...
```

Make sure that the test file doesn't exist before trying create one with `touch` command .

Comment: Hi Aleroot... Thanks alot for your time. But isn't this modification time obtained from $f->mdtm('test.time') with respect to remote ftp time?

We still can not get an idea about what is the timezone of remote ftp server, right?
modification time obtained will be somewhat 7 or 8 digits number.

Is there anything you can suggest?

Comment: @KasinathKottukkal Do you need the timezone as a string (e.g. "Europe/Berlin" or "CEST") or just as an offset ("+0200")?

Comment: @slavenRezic any way that is possible. i don't understand what can I infer from offset ("+0200")

Comment: @KasinathKottukkal Probably you want the offset, and probably just in seconds (and not in the ISO8601 timezone notation I used above). The hack as described by aleroot will give you exactly this.

Comment: @slavenRezic Does modification obtained from (stat file[9]) not depend upon which timezone server configured with?

Answer (score 1):

Does modification time obtained from (stat file[9]) not depend upon which timezone server configured with?

I touched a sample file almost simultaneously in two servers with different timzones. Modification time obtained was very similar. only last 4 digits were dissimilar.

```
Server 1
--------
root@- [~/ftp_kasi]# touch file
root@- [~/ftp_kasi]# perl mdtime.pl 
1380005862
root@- [~/ftp_kasi]# date
Tue Sep 24 02:59:19 EDT 2013
root@- [~/ftp_kasi]#

Server 2
--------
root@ffVM32 kasi]# touch file
[root@ffVM32 kasi]# perl mdtime.pl 
1380006066
[root@ffVM32 kasi]# date
Tue Sep 24 12:38:45 IST 2013
[root@ffVM32 kasi]#
```

---

```
 [root@ffVM32 kasi]# cat mdtime.pl 
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl

$file = "file";
#open my $fh,'<',$file or  die "Could not open file : $!\n";
#my $mdtime = (stat($fh))[9];

open (FILE, "file");
my $mdtime = (stat(FILE))[9];

print $mdtime."\n";
```

Comment: Do the `touch` on the ftp server, not locally.